# UIAutomation error in IOS

Tags: ios, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

I am getting this error in automation script written for my application. Below is my script:

```
var testName = "Test 1";
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
var app = target.frontMostApp();
var window = app.mainWindow(); 
window.textFields()[0].setValue("Hello");
```

In line 5 i am getting "cannot perform action on invalid element: UIAElementNil from target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().textFields()[0]".

what may be the reason for above error

Answer (score 1):

This is because the textFields()[0] is nil.

the mainWindow method return a window, and the textFields() should in a UIViewController's view.

Comment: Can i write automation script(using javascript) on ios, such that it can switch between applications. Also i want to know, whether i can access Settings in iPhone through automation script

Answer (score 0):

As FenixAdar already told, the problem is that you want to access your textfield element through a non-existent hierarchy chain.
To get the real hierarchy of the user interface elements you can insert the command `target.logElementTree();` before the problematic row. Using the output of this command you will be able to guess the correct expression.

But even easier is to record with Instuments as you fill this textfield and check the generated code.